# Regex in JS for checking number of occurences returns incorrect results

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find number of occurrences of "-X-" in a string. Where "X" is one letter.

So - I tried this Regex - `/\-[a-z]{1}\-/`.
However - I get incorrect results. For example - in this string:

`-a-b-c-`

I get:

`Array [ "-a-", "-c-" ]`

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't I get the `b` as well?

Answer (score 2):

The second `-` in your regex is *consuming* that character. Because the last `-` in `-a-` gets matched, for example, it starts looking for the next match *starting* at the point the last match ended - that is, *after* the second `-` in `-a-`.

Use lookahead instead:

```js
console.log(
  '-a-b-c-'.match(/-\w(?=-)/g)
);
```